# Comparing values from two different arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

So I am having this defined

```
class Passenger {

    let passengerId: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String, daysOnTrip: Int

    init(passengerId: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String, daysOnTrip: Int) {
        self.passengerId = passengerId
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.daysOnTrip = daysOnTrip
    }

}

let peopleTravelling = [
    Passenger(passengerId:1, firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", daysOnTrip: 10),
    Passenger(passengerId:2, firstName:"Seb", lastName:"Johns", daysOnTrip: 5),
    Passenger(passengerId:3, firstName:"Emilia", lastName:"Clarke", daysOnTrip: 7)
]

var tripDuration:Int
var tripCost:Double
var tripCostPerDay:Double

tripCost = 100.00
tripDuration = 10
tripCostPerDay = tripCost / Double(tripDuration)
```

What I am trying to find out is in each day of tripDuration, how many passengers are present based on daysOnTrip.

So I was thinking to add each day of the tripDuration into an array like this

```
var daysOfTrip: [Int] = []

for day in 0...tripDuration-1 {
    daysOfTrip.append(day)
}
```

And then I got stuck with how to find out for each day how many passengers there are available. I was thinking to somehow compare the day of the trip vs. the daysOnTrip from peopleTravelling.

e.g.
Day 1: 1<=10 && 1<=5 && 1<=7 => 3 passengers are present
...
Day 7: 7<=10 && 7<=5(not true) && 7<=10 => 2 passengers are present

But maybe my logic is off. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all map `peopleTravelling` to an array of the `daysOnTrip` values.

```
let daysArray = peopleTravelling.map{$0.daysOnTrip}
```

Then filter the array by the condition *is the value equal or greater than `day`* and `count` the occurrences

```
var daysOfTrip = [Int]()

for day in 1...tripDuration {
    daysOfTrip.append(daysArray.filter{$0 >= day}.count)
}
```

or *swiftier*

```
let daysOfTrip = (1...tripDuration).map{ day in
    daysArray.filter{$0 >= day}.count
}
```

The result is `[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]`

Be careful with the indices. The `day` in the loop starts with one but the result array starts with zero.

Comment: My programme returned me: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1] :/ Not sure why the first 1 to 10 are showing in the array?

Comment: Ops no worries I fixed it thanks for the assitsance